# Different behaviour of New-PSDrive in script and console

Tags: powershell

I'm having a small problem with powershell that's probably very easy... I get different behaviour if I run a command from the console than from a .ps1 file. The command;

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Name X -Root \\computer_name\x -Persist
```

If I run it from the console I get the behaviour that I want, namely a persistent X: drive that appears in the file manager. If I run it from a script, that only contains this line, I get no persistent drive.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `-Scope Global` to your New-PSDrive parameters.

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Name X -Root \\computer_name\x -Persist -Scope Global
```

As stated in [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829%28v=wps.620%29.aspx), by default, scope is local. If you read [about_Scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx), you'll see that local means the current scope which, for a script is, well, the script itself.

Comment: Great! Easy but I missed it... Thanks!